# android using GoogleAPI with the standard platform

Tags: java, android, api

I apologize for the newbie question as I am a newbie in developing for the android devices (started developing 2 days ago).

I understand though, that to make use of google map's location services, when you create a project and eclipse prompts you for a SDK target, you should target the GoogleAPI instead of the Android 4.0.3 (or whatever there is).

If such, will I be able to make use of everything there is in Android 4.0.3 when I click GoogleAPI ? Or is it possible to make use of the google api even if I target the Android 4.0.3 SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google enhanced version (with maps) of the 4.0.3 SDK in the AVD creation wizard is a superset of Android 4.0.3. The Google version just has additional google libraries included. There is no other supported way to get access to these libraries from the emulator or inside your development environment.

Comment: does that mean that if I dont target the googleAPI when I create my project, I won't be able to make use of the GoogleAPI's for android? Sorry, I found it hard to understand your explanation.

Comment: If you do not target a Google API version of Android with your workbench, you will not be able to compile code that interacts with Google libraries.

Comment: i see... so what you're saying is that it is impossible for me to make use of Geolocation (displaying a location in google map) without targeting the GoogleAPI. Are there no alternatives ?

Comment: There are no google provided alternatives. You could use a webview and the javascript api.